# How far meta-logical frameworks are from universal logic?

Tags: logic, proof-assistants

I am investigating metalogical-frameworks like Isabelle/Pure (very few information), http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page, http://abella-prover.org/ for encoding of new logics. And natural question arises - how far those frameworks are from universal logic? I am especially interested their capabilities to encode defeasible deontic logic and monoidal categorical logics.

Comment: What do you mean by "universal logic"?

Comment: It should be possible to embed any reasonable logic into
Isabelle/Pure, since Isabelle/Pure is a meta-logic, designed to embed
other logics. Alternatively, you can use any prover to do a deep
embedding of your target logic. The main question is pragmatic: how
much proof automation can you get for your target logic? Deep
embeddings tend to be quite terrible in this regard.

Comment: By universal logic I mean endeavours that are described in book series and journal Studies in Universal Logic and Logica Universalis http://link.springer.com/journal/11787 http://www.springer.com/series/7391 Specifically I mean institution theory http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764387075

Comment: And esspecially habilitation thesis "Institution theory and applications" http://www.imar.ro/~diacon/PDF/AbilitareTeza.pdf